# My boxes are not the same lengths

Tags: html

Below is my code for individuals providing testimonials. However, since each person has a different length testimonial, the boxes are different sizes. How do I make the boxes equal length?

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-style2">
            <article id="work">
                <header>
                    <h2>Achieve your nutritional goals.</h2>
                    <span>One step at a time.</span>
                </header>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="4u">
                            <section class="box box-style1">

                                <div class="circular" style= "margin: 0 auto">
                                    <img src="images/eric-hinman.jpg" style="width: 150px;"></img>
                                </div>
                                <h3>Eric</h3>
                                <p>"As an avid triathlete + owner of a Crossfit gym, I'm constantly looking for new ways to eat and live healthy. Zach has been a wealth of knowledge with respect to both."</p>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="4u">
                            <section class="box box-style1">
                                <div class="circular" style= "margin: 0 auto">
                                    <img src="images/Carl_Schramm.jpg" style="width: 155px;"></img>
                                </div>
                                <h3>Carl</h3>
                                <p>"Zach was very helpful in getting me into the paleo way of eating and the results were real.  Among other things, I'm back to my college weight."</p>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="4u">
                            <section class="box box-style1">
                            <div class="circular" style= "margin: 0 auto">
                                    <img src="images/JoshK.jpg" style="width: 150px;"></img>
                            </div>
                                <h3>Josh</h3>
                                <p>"Zach made me realize that healthy eating was an easy and realistic option."</p>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Whoever down voted this question, please include an explanation of your downvote.

Comment: @tintyethan I reckon it has to do with the lack of CSS, wasn't me though. On a side-note, `class="4u"` is no good, start the class with a letter, not a number. As it is now any related styles will be ignored, ex.: http://jsfiddle.net/E4nqF/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You can set the box heights and widths in css like this...

```
<style>
.boxes{
width:200px;
overflow:auto;
}
</style>
```

The overflow attribute allows for scrolling if the content is bigger than the box.

You can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SXXe6/